# Mongo DB Install as a window service

Tags: mongodb, installation

I am installing MongoDB as a service, installing it via command prompt. After few steps, it hanged on "waiting for connections on port 27017". Do I need to do anything to complete the installation.

Comment: maybe give [this tutorial](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/how-to-install-mongodb-server-on-windows-linux-4in) a try